Where (and when) does Sins of a Solar Empire take place?
Does Sins of a Solar Empire take place in our own Milky Way, and if so when is it set and where is the Earth?
Or is it set a completely different galaxy in a different universe?

It's honestly not that clear. Their official timeline only goes back about 10,000 years and the prehistory of this setting isn't ever described beyond vague references to the TEC having a homeworld that they're either defending or avenging.

For the homeworld!

One of the coalitions is certainly described as "human", fighting against a visibly "alien" Vasari who are described as having originated in the centre of this galaxy, but beyond that it's notable that the galaxy isn't named. The 'Sol' system is seen on maps, but it's not especially obvious that this is the human origin point and the developers seem to have simply incorporated a bunch of star names into their game (presumably from Wikipedia) rather than bothering to come up with hundreds of plausible-sounding names on their own.

Blair Fraser: There are three playable factions. The first is the Vasari Empire. These guys are really, really ancient aliens who want to rule about a quarter of the galaxy. For whatever reason, there was a cataclysmic event, some ten thousand years ago. These guys basically destroyed their entire civilization. They've been on the run through the galaxy all this time, stopping once in a while to pick up resources, pick up some of their ships, do some research, then move on again.
Now, these ancient guys, they run into the humans--the Trader Empire--and they [the humans] have to form a coalition to beat off these aliens. That's called the Trader Emergency Coalition. Now they're fighting each other, and the humans are slowly gaining ground against them. All their [human] vehicles are commercial, and things that are hatefully converted into weapons of war. So they're fighting it out, and they're at a stalemate at this point.
These other humans [the Advent], who were once part of the Trader network but were exiled for committing a bunch of crimes such as genetic enhancement, research into psionics, all this stuff that was very much taboo... They ran off to the other side of the galaxy after being exiled--now they're back with all new weapons of war. They find the [other] humans fighting these aliens, and now you've got a three-way battle going. It's not looking good for the humans, the non-enhanced humans. Their technology [the enhanced humans] is based on psi-tech, which is a technological enhancement of psionics. They have very weak structural ships, but they have all this stuff they can do that's unlike the weapons of the other two factions.
Sins of a Solar Empire Interview

